# Using user stylesheet to always show the 'From' line in Gmail composing message

Tags: javascript, css, gmail

I would like to create a user stylesheet in my Chrome browser to always show the `From` line in a Gmail response.

The default looks as follows:

[image]

I would like to have it as follows:

[image]

Gmail must use some JavaScript to unhide the `From`. This happens when you click on the recipient address.

Therefore my question. Is it overall possible to permanently show the `From` using CSS only or do I need some JavaScript here?

Comment: It's difficult because every time you refresh the GMail webpage all the IDs change, there is no easy way using only CSS

Comment: That's what I thought. Damned. How could a basic JS solution look like? What would it have to do to get the ID and set CSS properties?

Comment: You need some way to get what ID matches with that element, you'll need to investigate the event listeners in the GMail page and how it works.

Comment: Just another idea. Apparently Gmail uses some JavaScript to switch from `To-From` view to `Recipients` as soon as I select the `Subject` field or the body. Is it possible to block just this JavaScript so that it cannot be run and hide the `To-From` view?